# Basic real analysis - Convergence of the 2-series using subsequences of partial sums

Tags: real-analysis

[Link to image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKyp2.png)

I am following introduction to real analysis by Bartle. Bit stumped at 3.7.6.(c), as shown in the link - why does it suffice to show that any given subsequence of the partial sums is bounded? Monotone Convergence only applies if the entire sequence is bounded, I thought. Is this something to do with the particular series (1/n^2)?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: A monotone sequence is bounded if and only if some subsequence is bounded.

Comment: I see, thank you!